# How to Display a word or anyother Document into asp.net page without downloading from sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

my project is a finance based website,

now when ever we upload a word,PDF or Excel document the file is Directly saved in sharepoint and a link is provided to user or the the person whom he submits the invoice or application but according to the new requirement we should provide a view button that basically display the content to the file Kinda like opening a word file on Gmail or yahoo..!!,
as far as i know to open them the file must be physically be on the server to be opened by viewer but the file is uploaded in Sharepoint directly as mentioned earlier
and i can't write any code for the file to be downloaded on server or on client machine coz 
reason 1: File may be to Large
reason 2: Performance will be reduced

so is there any other way i can open that respective file in a viewer or popup without downloading it on server or on client machine

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly , you want view the file in browser ?

**Use Office Web Apps with SharePoint**

[Install office webapp](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/installing-office-web-apps-for-sharepoint-2010/)

[Activate it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837418(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: i can't expect client to have it installed